# Does Elm's lambda syntax support destructuring?

Tags: elm

Can I write

```
\(a, b) -> ...
```

and expect a tuple parameter to be destructured?

Comment: What happens when you [try](http://elm-lang.org/try) it?

Comment: I was getting a compiler error

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, you can...

For example, following code works.

```elm
import Html exposing (text)

main =
  ("Hello", "World!")
    |> \(a,b) -> a ++ " " ++ b
    |> text
```